# Is there a way to open up a html file in a browser from a .NET application?

Tags: .net, html

I have a HTML file I want to open in a browser. I want to open this using a .NET application. 
Being more specific, I want to open this file in a browser each time say the user inputs a variable value ='abc' say. 
I'm using C# in .NET
Is there anyway to do this?
Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to know just one more thing : Can I open the HTML file with like a parameter, like for instance in my .NET code I have a place where each person enters his name. In the HTML file, I want an alert saying "Hi Name" as soon as the browser opens. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: @wittythota - You should ask this as a separate question, really, but probably the easiest way to do this is to create a modified file for each time you launch the browser.  You may need to deal with clearing-up the temporary files in some way, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Further Reference : The answer to the question can be found here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/e43012b2-8d72-423a-99bd-c6a4ef358077
It uses MSScriptControl and the JS code can just be added into the .NET application as shown. The class name shown should be ScriptControl, not ScriptControlClass.

Thanks,
Thothathri

Answer (score 5):

`Process.Start(nameOfHtmlFile)` will launch the default browser.

Answer (score 3):

The [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) lets you load html files or you can use... System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "C:\FilePath.html");

Comment: +1 for showing how to force IE. I ran in to this issue when my link would open a document on a SharePoint site but the default browser was Firefox.

Comment: +1 for covering `WebBrowser`, in case the OP wanted it to be *in* the app.  I'd suggest not hard-coding the browser to IE, though.  They may be using Chrome, FireFox, Opera, etc.  Their browser selection might be even more varied if they're running the app on Mono/Linux.  I suppose that option might be helpful in some cases, though :)

Comment: thanks DaMartyr, I want to know just one more thing : Can I open the HTML file with like a parameter, like for instance in my .NET code I have a place where each person enters his name. In the HTML file, I want an alert saying "Hi Name" as soon as the browser opens. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Generate the HTML file on the fly with the appropriate Javascript Alert (including the user's input) and load that file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");`

[Source](http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp_636597.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a static method System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("YOUR_URL");

In this case you must to replace string "YOUR_URL" by url adress.